# was working vs had been working

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

I am going to make up two similar sentences.

(1) I didn't have time to do anything else because I **was** working on my project.

(2) I didn't have time to do anything else because I **had been** working on my project.

I don't understand how the two tenses simple past continuous (was) and past perfect continuous (had been) change the meaning of the sentences.

Can someone please explain it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence,

> I didn't have time to do anything else (project **B**) because I was working on my project **A**.

A possible nuance is

> I was working on my project **A** *(instead of project B)*.

could mean you chose to work on *project **A*** instead of *project **B***.

> I had been working on my project **A** *(before starting project **B**)*.

might be understood as *project **A*** got in the way of *project **B***.